# Unable to use airmon-ng, blocking processes

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, network-monitoring, aircrack-ng

I am quite new to aircrack-ng, and learning it. But i got stuck on the airmon.

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Details about system:

```
Operating System: Windows 8
Wireless: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11 b/g/n (2.4Ghz)
```

I have tried following but still not able to start the wireless card in monitor mode:

```
sudo airmon-ng 


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth0        Unknown     wl - [phy0]
```

and `sudo airmon-ng` returns

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
5694    avahi-daemon
5695    avahi-daemon
5743    NetworkManager
5818    wpa_supplicant
6951    dhclient
Process with PID 6951 (dhclient) is running on interface eth0


Interface   Chipset     Driver

eth0        Unknown     wl - [phy0]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

`lspci | grep Network`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
```

I tried killing all the process using `airmon-ng check kill` but they again get restarted, I think this is because networking is automatically started in ubuntu.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Tidalwave. Next time onwards I will check these things before posting. Anyways I got stuck at this place and I am not able to start the interface in monitor mode.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, kill those processes, last time I used it it was in fact necessary to kill the listed processes.

Comment: But alex, I killed all those processes using `kill processid` but the again restarted automatically

Comment: Try stopping or ending them then. If you have GUI `Applications > System Tools > System Monitor`.

Comment: well does that seriously make sense. coz I don't find those processes listed in the process list in system monitor

Comment: I was going to rephrase your title into a question... But, I'm not sure what the question is now.

Comment: I have rephrased the question title.

Comment: i tired all things mentoined but didn't worked ,did u solved this ...how can you put some details

Answer (score 1):

Already answered by codeo, but in details:

Before using airodump-ng, you have to start a virtual interface:

> `airmon-ng start` *your_physical_wifi_int*

Then `ifconfig -a` should show something like `mon0`.

and at last `airodump-ng mon0` should show your neighbour Wi-Fi AP and clients.

Comment: HI Card could you please help me, I have edited the question.